# Problems with code that involves outputting the fibonnaci sequence when given a starting number and the number of terms called for

Tags: r

Here is the question I am working on from homework in a statistics class

Create a function that can run this loop to generate a Fibonacci sequence of any size, starting from any given number (i.e. it does not have to start with 1). So for example, a sequence of length x from number y, where x and y are inputs to the function.

Here is my code so far. My issue with the code is that whenever I say select 7 for the length, I will get back an even number of outputs. This number is dependent on while loop where I change the "nterms" value and I do not know how to correct it. Everything else seems to work.

```
{
# take input from the user
nterms = readline(prompt="How many terms? ")
nterms = as.integer(nterms) 
# take input from the user
x = readline(prompt="Starting Number?")
x = as.integer(x)
}

Phi <- (1 + sqrt(5))/(2)
phi <- 1/(Phi)
i <- 1

fib1 <- ((Phi)^(x-1)-(-phi)^(x-1))/(sqrt(5))
fib2 <- ((Phi)^(x-2)-(-phi)^(x-2))/(sqrt(5))
fibonnaci <- c()

while (i <= nterms-3)
{
  fib1 <- fib1+fib2
  fib2 <- fib1+fib2
  fibonnaci=c(fibonnaci,fib1,fib2)
  i <- i+1
}
fibonnaci
```

Comment: Every time you go through the loop, you add two terms.  So of course you'll get an even length output.  You probably want to put `fibonnaci <- c(fib1, fib2)` before your while loop. Inside the loop, only add one to the sequence.

Comment: I tried to do that but when I did, it did not fix the issue for me.

Comment: Try referring to the two most recent elements in the sequence with something like `fibonnaci[i] + fibonnaci[i+1]`

Comment: Where would that command go exactly?

Comment: You need to replace the code inside your while loop.  Part of that replacement should be the code fragment I mentioned.

Comment: I tried that and it broke. I am actually lost and confused but I dont want to come off as asking for the answer as that breaks the integrity of this website.

Comment: Your approach to adding terms to the sequence inside the while loop is good. But the thing that you’re appending to it is not quite right. You need to add the sum of the previous two terms in the sequence. You can access these using `i`

Comment: What would I change exactly? Whenever I change fib1 to the thing you said I get the Null space as an output.

Comment: Did you put `fibonnaci <- c(fib1, fib2)` right before the while loop?

Comment: After you do this, you don’t need `fib1` or `fib2` again